# Consuming Yahoo pipes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yahoo-pipes, mechanicalturk

I am writing a javascript client for mechanical turk and since mechanical turk does not provide a JSON API I am passing their data through Yahoo Pipes to format it as JSON. I now have a lot of difficulty reading in this JSON (due to cross-domain incompatibilities) How should I read the output of the yahoo pipe properly that can be parsed by .parseJSON())

I'd like to emphasize that it is a client side tool (with javascript) and I do not want to set up a server with PHP to consume the feed.

```
{"count":1,"value":{"title":"Mturk Caller","description":"Pipes Output","link":"http:\/\/pipes.yahoo.com\/pipes\/pipe.info?_id=4dc935cadabe6d6bed8821ecabd07d6d","pubDate":"Fri, 25 Feb 2011 03:16:50 -0800","generator":"http:\/\/pipes.yahoo.com\/pipes\/","callback":"","items":[{"OperationRequest":{"RequestId":"5bf099e6-20e7-46f1-bd53-87058120498e"},"GetAccountBalanceResult":{"AvailableBalance":{"Amount":"10000.000","CurrencyCode":"USD","FormattedPrice":"$10,000.00"},"Request":{"IsValid":"True"}},"description":"","title":""}]}}
```

and the pipe address that I use is

```
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?AWSAccessKeyId=1Q7SH20FYTKQQ05SCDG2&Operation=GetAccountBalance&Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester&Signature=wPBfRCe5tn8vlQVv0//yc4Tm/iA=&Timestamp=2011-02-25T11:16:52Z&Version=2008-08-02&_id=4dc935cadabe6d6bed8821ecabd07d6d&_render=json&callback=?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `_callback` not plain `callback`

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more.

Comment: Yahoo! Pipes predates the convention to use `callback` to specify what function to wrap the JSON in a JSON-P call with. It uses `_callback`. Your URL uses `callback` which is therefore ignored.